# How to update Java 8 EA (Windows 8)?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8

Each time I update Java 8 EA it changes path so I'm forced to run Intellij Idea with it. For now it leads to IDE's malfunction so I have to remove it from path. When I run in Command Prompt:

```
> java -version
java version "1.8.0-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-ea-b116)
```

Till now I've been deleting `$WINDOWS\system32\java.exe` and re-installing JDK7. May be there is a better option?

**ADDED**

I install it to a custom folder to be able to fallback to a previous release and I also choose it to install JRE.

Comment: on my machine it always goes to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0

Answer (score 2):

For running 32-bit IDEA, create and set the environment variable `IDEA_JDK` to a 32-bit Java 7 JDK root directory. For running 64-bit IDEA, create and set `IDEA_JDK_64` to a 64-bit Java 7 JDK.